# Power expression for a dynamic force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, power

Given that:

$$W=\int_{x_0}^x \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{x}$$

and assuming $F$ is time dependent, we get:

$$\frac{dW}{dt} = \int_{x_0}^x \frac{d\vec{F}}{dt}\cdot d\vec{x}+\vec{F}(x,t)\cdot \vec{v}$$

How come then that $P=Fv$? Why does the first term of $\displaystyle{\int_{x_0}^x \frac{d\vec{F}}{dt}\cdot d\vec{x}}$ sums to zero?

Comment: What makes you think it sums to zero? Dynamic means changes with time, so dF/dt must be non zero, and probably any integral or sum of it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental relation is $dW=F\,dx$.  If you divide both sides of this by $dt$, you get $P=Fv$.

In your integral expression, you need to express $F$ implicitly as a function $F(t(x))$, using the trajectory $x(t)$. This means that $t$ is no longer an independent variable inside the integral; instead $F$ is just a function of position $F(x)$, which means that the first term in your expression does not exist.